# nested execution occurrence in Rhapsody

Tags: callback, sequence-diagram, rhapsody

Going through [this documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rsdvhelp/v6r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xtools.modeler.doc/topics/cexoccur_m.html), I figured that we can make nested execution occurrence in Rhapsody.

When I tried making the nested execution occurrence in my sequence diagram, I was unable to do it. The documentation seems outdated and the steps are not quite clear.

Can anyone point out a link/tutorial that tells how to make nested execution occurrence?

P.S. I am building a sequence diagram for 2 classes that interact with one another. Function from class A calls function from class B and the process repeats 2 times.

Answer (score 0):

That documentation is for Rational Systems Developer, which is a different product. I expect you have Rational Rhapsody System Designer Edition? The confusion is forgivable!

Unfortunately, Rational Rhapsody does not support nested execution occurrences. Sorry it's not the answer you're looking for!

cheers,
Simon